# Veeam HotAdd causing Worker Thread Exhaustion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have a SQL 2012 Always ON AG with 2 nodes and a file share witness.  We have 207 Customer DBs in the AG on a box with 12 Cores and Instance configured for 60 GB RAM.  I have 1 Secondary configured for Synchronous Mode locally.

Each night we do full backups of those 207 DBs on the secondary.  What is strange is we also do Veeam backups of the SQL Server (not any application-aware processing or anything as I want to handle backup chain myself) each night we end up with worker thread exhaustion which terminates the AG and 30 seconds later it comes back.  I can’t imagine the Veeam backup process or the VMWare Snapshotting process would use any SQL worker threads but maybe I am missing something?

Why does Veeam HotAdd cause worker thread exhaustion? Have you ever come across this?  I even changed the Veeam backup time and the worker thread exhaustion time moved with it.

Comment: After further review looks like these are 2 separate issues.  I believe the STUN time of 5 seconds is causing the AG to terminate and then reaquire 30 seconds later.   That specific instance does have more AG dbs on it that the other SQL instances and Backups run at that time on the secondary which also uses a thread as well...